# Why does less than not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this seems very straightforward, but why does this comparison stop working?

```
if (nmax < num){
        nmax = num;
    }
```

I have this inside a loop, looking for the largest number.  The first number is 105, then 89, then 99. then a whole munch of numbers larger than 99.  The first number is the number to be tested, the second number is the 'current max number'.  Why is this so broken????

```
101 101 VM2734:8
88 88 VM2734:8
99 99 VM2734:8
105 99 VM2734:8
756 99 VM2734:8
97 99 VM2734:8
92 99 VM2734:8
104 99 VM2734:8
98 99 VM2734:8
100 99 VM2734:8
95 99 VM2734:8
89 99 VM2734:8
96 99 VM2734:8
755 99 VM2734:8
100 99 VM2734:8
...
```

EDIT:

here is the whole code:

```
var nmax = 0;
    $(notams.rows().nodes()).each(function(key, id){
        var num = $(id).find("td:eq(0)").html();
        if (num > nmax){
            nmax = num;
        }
        console.log(num+' '+nmax);
    });
```

Comment: That's not the code causing your trouble

Comment: better if you post full code.

Comment: Probably you're comparing strings instead of actual numbers ('99' is *bigger* than '101')

Comment: That's what it was.  The first 3 were numbers and string after that.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

num was sometimes a string.  parseInt and everything works great!

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping them in parseInt

```
if (parseInt(nmax) < parseInt(num)){
        nmax = num;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do numerical comparison

```
var nmax = 0;
$(notams.rows().nodes()).each(function (key, id) {
    var num = parseInt($(id).find("td:eq(0)").html().trim(), 10);
    if (num > nmax) {
        nmax = num;
    }
    console.log(num + ' ' + nmax);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the problematic code, it means you're comparing strings. `"99"` is *bigger* than `"101"`. You'll have to convert them to numbers, e.g.:

```
nmax = Number(nmax); // or parseInt(nmax)
num = Number(num);   // or parseInt(num)
// ...
if (nmax < num){
    nmax = num;
}
```